# How to write CSV with a different number of python values

Tags: python

I need to register the saving of values in. csv, but the number of values changes in each product, I can not understand how to do it correctly, so that each value is recorded under its own parameter, as shown in the file, please tell me

I will also attach a file to make it easier to understand what I need

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
HOST = 'https://samara.vseinstrumenti.ru'
URL = 'https://samara.vseinstrumenti.ru/santehnika/vse-dlya-vodosnabzheniya/avtonomnaya-kanalizatsiya/'
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_url(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    urls = soup.find_all('div',class_='product-tile grid-item')
    for item in urls: 
        time.sleep(5)
        data_collection(HOST + item.find(class_='title').find('a').get('href'))

def get_name(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    name = soup.find('h1',class_='title').text
    return name

def get_description(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    description = soup.find('div',itemprop="description").text
    return description

def get_specifications_parameter(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    dotted_list = soup.find('ul',class_='dotted-list')
    parameters = dotted_list.find_all('span',class_='text')
    return parameters

def get_specifications_meaning(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    dotted_list = soup.find('ul',class_='dotted-list')
    meaning = dotted_list.find_all('span',class_='value')
    return meaning

def get_photo(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    photo = soup.find('div',class_="item -active").find('img').get('src')
    return photo

def get_price(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    price = soup.find('span',class_='current-price').text
    return price

def data_collection(URL):
    html = get_html(URL)
    name = get_name(html.text)  
    description = get_description(html.text)
    specifications_parameter = get_specifications_parameter(html.text)
    meaning = get_specifications_meaning(html.text)
    # photo = get_photo(html.text)
    price = get_price(html.text)
    

def start():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_url(html.text)
    else:
        print('Network error')
start()
```

I tried to do this, but it doesn't work like this

```
def save_file_walid(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow(item)
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uGoW1kpsDGDA-Zh7SiiCDcg9cf2lHQUd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to know more about what's really happening.
First of all, the source path is correctly named? I mean, for example, a correct path name would be:

> "/root/source path/content.csv"
> with the file's name inside the path.

Looking at your code, at the end of the data_collection function you can add:

```
data = [name, description, specifications_parameter, meaning, price]
save_file_walid(data, path)
```

To store the data into the csv file. Then, in your save_file_walid() you don't need to use the for loop if you write only the data list. You just need:

```
def save_file_walid(item, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
         writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
         writer.writerow(item)
```

Finally, before storing the data you can add only once somewhere in your code:

```
data = ["name", "description", "specifications_parameter", "meaning", "price"]
save_file_walid(data, path)
```

to create the file (if there's not been created yet) with the name of each column.

Hope this gonna be helpfully to you)

Comment: I didn't quite understand what to do, I tried in different ways, but it didn't work out

Comment: What didn't work? the csv file creation? data into the csv file doesn't seem correct? `import csv` has been added?

Comment: Write to me in the telegram please @Pivovar_Kola